# ¿Cómo puedo añadir elementos a la etiqueta root en XML con java sin que me duplique espacios?

Tags: java, xml

Tengo un XML en java, quiero añadir elementos a la etiqueta root, pero cuando se crea el nuevo archivo me pone espacios entre las etiquetas. Si añado más elementos me vuelve a duplicar los espacios.

Está es la función que uso para añadir un nuevo elemento a la etiqueta root del XML:

```
public static void addElement(String fichero) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
        String element;
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(fichero);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        
        do {
            element = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Introduzca el nombre de la etiqueta", "Crear XML", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            if(element == null || element != null && element.equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre no puede estar vacío", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } while(element == null || element != null && element.equals(""));
        
        Element el = document.createElement(element);
        el.setTextContent(" ");
        root.appendChild(el);
        
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fichero);
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
```

Este en el XML sin modificar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rootElement>
    <element1> </element1>      
    <element2> </element2>
</rootElement>
```

Este es el XML modificado la primera vez:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rootElement>
        
    <element1> </element1>
        
    <element2> </element2>
    
    <element3> </element3>
</rootElement>
```

Si vuelvo a añadir un elemento me duplica los espacios entre las etiquetas. No se muy bien como solucionarlo.

XML modificado la tercera vez:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rootElement>
            
    
    <element1> </element1>
            
    
    <element2> </element2>
        
    
    <element3> </element3>
    
    <element4> </element4>
</rootElement>
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se provoca al usar la indentación:

```
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

este problema ya fue [reportado como un bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8262285), haciendo referencia a este ejemplo:

```
---------- BEGIN SOURCE ----------
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class XmlBugExample {

    private static final String S_KEY_INDENT_AMOUNT = "{http://xml.apache.org/xalan}indent-amount";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n"
                + "<users>\n"
                + "\t<!-- pre-existing entry BEGIN -->\n"
                + "\t\t <user> <!-- a user -->\n"
                + "\t\t <name>A name</name>\n"
                + "\t\t <email>An email</email>\n"
                + "\t\t </user>\n"
                + " <!-- pre-existing entry END -->\n"
                + "</users>";

        Source in = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXML));
        StreamResult out = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(S_KEY_INDENT_AMOUNT, "4");
        transformer.transform(in, out);

        String result = out.getWriter().toString();

        System.out.println("\n###### JAVA VERSION: "
                + System.getProperty("java.vendor") + " "
                + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
        System.out.println("\n###### RESULT:\n");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("\n###### RESULT SHOWING WHITESPACES:\n");
        System.out.println(result.replaceAll("\\t", "\\\\t").replaceAll(" ", "\u00B7"));
    }

}
```

> Tenga en cuenta que los espacios en blanco son significativos sin un
> esquema. El procesador tratará un nodo de texto como es, un nodo de
> texto, independientemente de su contenido. Si lo que desea es un
> "reformateo" (eliminar los espacios en blanco y agregar una nueva
> sangría como se muestra en el código), considere aplicar una hoja de
> estilo para eliminar los espacios en blanco.

Aquí mismo se propone una solución alternativa:

> **Use una hoja de estilo (stylesheet) para eliminar los nodos de texto
> vacíos**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.